# How to check how often a file is updated via terminal?

Tags: terminal, command-line, command

I have a file that is being updated via a script I do not have access. I am trying to see how often it gets updated.

One thing that occurred to me was doing a:

`watch -n 0.1 "ls -la"`

The problem with this command is that maybe the file is updated faster than my `-n` parameter.
The second problem is that the resolution of the output is in minutes, thus, I cannot see if the files is updated every second or less than that.

Is there a more clever/elegant way of looking into how often a file is updated in the terminal?